# How to sort a list of strings following a certain pattern

Tags: python, list, sorting, design-patterns

I want to sort every lists of strings, such as :

```
list1 = ['3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001', '3DT1_S001', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001']
list2 = ['3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S002']
```

following the pattern `[ '3DT1_S##', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S##', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S##', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S##']`

the outcome should be :

```
list1 = [ '3DT1_S001', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001']
list2 = [ '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S002']
```

I tried to play a bit with the sorted method, but with no luck !

Any help ?

Comment: Does `##` mean anything after that?

Answer (score 5):

My two cents... This has a 'patternList' variable that defines the order. This is probably the easiest (most human readable, expandable) way to implement this: no messy if-elses. Also, the list items with the same starting pattern is ordered by the rest of the string.

The `list1.sort(key = myKey)` means that for each list item `myKey` function is executed before sorting. `myKey` function modifies the sorted list items **for sorting purposes only** in a way that normal sort will do what you want. In the output sorted list the original list item is not used (not the one `myKey` modified).

In the example below, the myKey function splits the list items in to two parts and labels the first with integer according to patternList variable. Normal sort can handle the returned tuple in a way you want.

```
list1 = ['3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001', '3DT1_S001', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001']
list2 = ['3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S003', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001']

def myKey(x):
    # create the 'order list' for starting pattern
    patternsList = [ '3DT1_S', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S']
    for i in range(len(patternsList)): # iterate patterns in order
        pattern = patternsList[i]
        if x.find(pattern) == 0: # check if x starts with pattern
            # return order value i and x without the pattern
            return (i, x.replace(pattern, '')) 

    # if undefined pattern is found, put it to first
    return (-1, x)

    # alternatively if you want undefind to be last
    # return (len(patternList)+1, x)


print list1
list1.sort(key = myKey)
print list1

print list2
list2.sort(key = myKey)
print list2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define a *key function* that returns tuples in the required order, and then pass the function to the `key` parameter of `sorted` like so.

```
>>> def key_fn(x):
...     tags = x.split('_')
...     if tags[1][0] == 'S':
...         return (0, int(tags[1][1:]))
...     elif tags[1] == 'noPN':
...         return (1, int(tags[3][1:]))
...     elif tags[1] == 'PN':
...         if tags[2] == 'noDIS3D':
...             return (2, int(tags[3][1:]))
...         else:
...             return (3, int(tags[3][1:]))
... 
>>> list1 = ['3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001', '3DT1_S001', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001']
>>> sorted(list1, key=key_fn)
['3DT1_S001', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001']
```

Comment: @jamylak OP's requirement was very specific. And the answer does work for his requirements. If his requirements change for his particular problem, he can always take the general idea (which is returning tuples in sort order) and modify according to his own requirement.

Comment: I think I have to agree with @jamylak here.  I can't tell if this works or not without thinking through the prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

This method works by sorting by the index of the first pattern found.

```
>>> import re
>>> list1 = ['3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001', '3DT1_S001', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001']
>>> list2 = ['3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S002']
>>> patterns = [ '3DT1_S', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S']
>>> pattern = '|'.join('(%s)'%x for x in patterns)
>>> pattern #Creates a regex pattern with each pattern as a group in order
'(3DT1_S)|(3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S)|(3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S)|(3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S)'
>>> def sort_key(x):
        return re.match(pattern,x).lastindex
>>> list1, list2 = [sorted(l, key=sort_key) for l in (list1,list2)]
>>> list1
['3DT1_S001', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001']
>>> list2
['3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S002']
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an approach that takes a list of 'prefixes' that are used to group the list before sorting.  Each item is added to the group corresponding to the *first*, and only the first, prefix that it matches.

```
list1 = ['3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001', '3DT1_S001', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001']
list2 = ['3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S002', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S002', '3DT1_S002']

prefixes = [ '3DT1_S', '3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S', '3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S', '3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S']

def f(l):
    result = []
    for p in prefixes:               # for each prefix, in order
        a = []                       # items in the group
        b = []                       # items not in the group
        for x in l:                  # for each item
            if x.startswith(p):      # does the item match the prefix?
                a.append(x)          # add it to the group
            else:  
                b.append(x)          # add it to the "rest"
        result.append(sorted(a))     # sort the group and save it for the result
        l = b                        # continue with the non-group elements
    return result
```

And here's the result:

```
>>> f(list1)
[['3DT1_S001'], ['3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S001'], ['3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S001'], ['3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S001']]
>>> f(list2)
[['3DT1_S002'], ['3DT1_noPN_DIS3D_S002'], ['3DT1_PN_noDIS3D_S002'], ['3DT1_PN_DIS3D_S002']]
```

Comment: For copy-'n-paste purposes it's better to use `#` for comments, not `//`.

Comment: If one prefix starts with another (e.g. "3DT1_noP" and "3DT1_noP2_fred", to make something up) then won't the item be appended multiple times?

Comment: @DSM, no, it will be removed from `l`, so it can only be placed in one group.  for any item, it will only be placed in the first prefix group it matches.